# MacOS assembly linker throws error while linking

Tags: macos, assembly, linker, nasm

I'm trying to compile and link an assembly file to an executable with NASM and the standard LD linker on my MacBook Air M1. I have no problems with getting the .o file, but if I want to link it with LD, it throws that error:

```
ld: file not found: elf_i386
```

Command:

```
ld -m elf_i386 -s -o hello hello.o
```

What do I have to change?

Answer (score 2):

Those are options for GNU `ld` on x86 Linux. (Note the ELF part of the target object-file format, and the i386). MacOS uses the MachO object-file format, not ELF, and apparently their `ld` takes different options.

Also, MacOS hasn't supported 32-bit x86 for a few versions now, so an M1 mac with an AArch64 CPU definitely can't run 32-bit x86 executables natively.

---

**So get an emulator for a 32-bit Linux environment if you want to follow a tutorial for that environment**, or find a tutorial for AArch64 MacOS. Or possibly x86-64 MacOS which should still work transparently thanks to Rosetta, but make sure single-step debugging actually works. That's an essential part of a development environment for learning asm.

**Assembly language is not portable at all, you need a tutorial for the OS, CPU-architecture, and mode (32-bit vs. 64-bit) that you're going to built in.**  Don't waste your time trying to port a tutorial at the same time you're learning the basics it's trying to teach.  You'd have to already know both systems to know which parts of the code and build commands need to change.

Comment: Do you know a good tutorial for Assembly on MacOS?

Comment: @lasse1711: I don't know of one myself.  I'm sure there are lots, but the trick is finding a *good* one.  As with many topics I think, some people seem to write tutorials as a learning exercise for themselves, so the info isn't always reliable.  One of the tutorial links in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info does mention being for Linux or x86-64 MacOS (search "macos" on that page), so I think I must have had a look at it since I remember writing the description of it in the tag wiki.